# Error with divides, Haskell

Tags: haskell

My code, where n = 4:

```
f n = map (4/) [1..n]

main = do
    n <- getLine
    print(f (product(map read $ words n :: [Int])))
```

If I use in terminal `map (4/) [1..n]` I get a right answer: `[4.0,2.0,1.3333333333333333,1.0]`.
But in my program it's doesn't work, error message is: `No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of`f'`
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Adding type signatures to top-level bindings like `f` can help in fixing these kind of issues. Without a signature GHC can infer a type you did not meant to use, and report the error much later, often causing surprise and confusion in the programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `n` is an `Int` which isn't a `Fractional` type. Those are the ones that support division using the `/` operator. You can either replace `/` with `div` to get integer division (truncates to whole numbers) or you can add `fromIntegral` to convert the `n` to the correct type.

Your code should look something like

```
 f n = map (4/) [1..fromIntegral n]
```

To clarify a bit more: Your function f ultimately does division on the parameter that's given to it. This leads the type inference engine to determine that those parameters should be `Fractional` types. Then you use that function in your `main` you explicitly give it an `Int`.

That's why the error says "You gave me an `Int`. There's no instance for `Fractional Int` (read as, '`Int` isn't a `Fractional` type') and I need it to be because you're passing an `Int` into something that requires that instance."

Comment: Oh, I can't do that `f n = map (n/) [1..fromIntegral n]` :( How I can fix it?

Comment: You need to convert the `n` you're dividing as well. So `(fromIntegral n /)`